# Ionic - UI Router duplicates module instance for different parameter passed to state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

When a **$state.go()** is applied to a state with **parameter** in UI-Router, a new instance of module is being created.

For example:

```
.state('tab.activity-chat', {
    url: '/activity-chat/:activityId',
    views: {
        'tab-my-activities': {
            template: '<activity-chat></activity-chat>'
        }
    }
})
$state.go('tab.activity-chat', { activityId: activity._id});
```

`<activity-chat></activity-chat>` - this is my module that initializing every time I'm routing to
'tab.activity-chat' with different parameter (activityId).

In browser I can see duplicate HTML code :
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6xJ3.jpg)

How do I stop new instances of my module(directive/controller/view)?
I want to use the same module for any data that $stateParams passed.

Comment: did you found a solution?